# Copy a specific range of rows once conditions are met and paste it to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets:
Sheet1 - "raw"
Sheet2 - "copy"

The button that has the macro code is in Sheet2. Once I click the button, the macro will run with the first condition that if cell B2 in Sheet1 has a value, it should copy row B2:X2 and paste it to the second row (after the header) of Sheet2. But if no value, it should loop to the next row and repeat the operation.

The condition I'm having trouble with adding, is as follows:
If cell X2 is equal to 'Yes', it should copy row B2:M2 and row range Y2:AH2 of Sheet1 then paste it to range B3:N3 of Sheet2 and O3:X3 of Sheet2. This same goes for row AI2, AT2, BE2, BP2, and CA2 wherein values contain Yes or No. But if the answer is 'No' or has no value, it will loop on the next row in Sheet1 then run again the same copy method until the last row. But it shouldnt copy a blank row.

Below is the current code for the first condition.

```vb
Sub Copy3()

    Dim srcws As Worksheet
    Dim destws As Worksheet

    Set srcws = Worksheets("raw")
    Set destws = Worksheets("copy")
    
    srcws.Select
    SecondRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To SecondRow
        ThisValue = Cells(i, 2).Value
        If ThisValue <> " " Then
            srcws.Range("B" & i & ":W" & i).Copy _
                Destination:=destws.Range("B" & i)
        End If
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This is somehow working though i dont want to copy blank rows only those have values on cell B2.

Any help will be appreciated for this to work!

For the Second condition - If cell X2 is equal to 'Yes', then it will copy range B2:M2 and range Y2:AH2 from Sheet1 to next row of Sheet2 which is under the row of copied data from first condition.

Basically because every row has the employee data and first employee dependent from range B2:W2 of Sheet1 then every row cell of X (Sheet1) contains value of 'Yes' or 'No'. That if row X2 value is Yes, it should copy the employee details from Sheet1 range B2:M2 and paste it to range B3:N3 of Sheet2. Then copy range Y2:AH2 from Sheet1 and paste it to range O3:X3 of Sheet2

I hope this will help explain the second condition. Though i dont have the code yet created for this.

Thank you!

Condition 2:
If cell X = Yes, then copy range B:M from Sheet1 and paste it to next row range B:N of Sheet2 and copy range Y:AH of Sheet1 and paste it to next row range O:X of Sheet2
But if No, go to next row of Sheet1 and apply condition 1

Condition 3:
If cell AI = Yes then copy range B:M from Sheet1 and paste it to next row range B:N of Sheet2 and copy range AJ:AS of Sheet1 and paste it to next row range O:X of Sheet2

Condition 4:
If cell AT = Yes then copy range B:M from Sheet1 and paste it to next row range B:N of Sheet2 and copy range AU:BD of Sheet1 and paste it to next row range O:X of Sheet2

Condition 5:
If cell BE = Yes then copy range B:M from Sheet1 and paste it to next row range B:N of Sheet2 and copy range BF:BO of Sheet1 and paste it to next row range O:X of Sheet2

Condition 6:
If cell BP = Yes then copy range B:M from Sheet1 and paste it to next row range B:N of Sheet2 and copy range BQ:BZ of Sheet1 and paste it to next row range O:X of Sheet2

Sorry for the confusion but let me know for any details needed.

Comment: You need to use expressions like cell `B2` and range `B2:X2` to be understood. Also, if you don't have a code, you can easily create one by using the `Macro Recorder`. Turn it on and start copy/pasting. When done, turn it off, and in the `Visual Basic Editor` (`F11`) in `Module1` you will find the code which you can test with the play button (`F5`) and if something is wrong you can explain what is wrong and then you can copy it [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71432386/edit). Never mind the format, someone will fix it for now.

Comment: Hi! Below is currently my code for the first condition. In which somehow working though i dont want to copy blank rows only those have values on cell B2.

Comment: Great for the code. The code covers the first condition. Now you need to explain the second condition. As I said, use words like cell and range. This *This same goes for row AJ2, AU2, BF2, BQ2, and CB2* I don't understand.

Comment: `" "` represents a space, not a blank. For blanks, you need to use `""`. What does this *copy row B2 to N2 and row AA2 to AI2* mean? Where do you want to copy those?

Comment: I have modified your question a little. Could you now better explain your second condition because it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I have added the second condition details. Hope you could still help me on this. Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to copy data for an employee, B:X, to Sheet2 and then below that the data for each of the employee's dependants?

Comment: You need to decide if `B:M` or `B:N` and I still don't understand *This same goes for row AI2, AT2, BE2, BP2, and CA2`*.

Comment: Are you trying to copy data for an employee, B:X, to Sheet2 and then below that the data for each of the employee's dependants? - Sorry for the confusion but just to be clear the answer is Yes, but the range B:W from Sheet1 is just for the first condition of copying and pasting it to Sheet2. While for row cell X, AI, AT, BE, BP and CA it has question "Do you wish to enroll another dependent" if answer is Yes it should copy range B2:M2 and range Y2:AH2 of Sheet1 and paste it to range B3:N3 and range O3:X3 of Sheet2